# Linking an image to the post it's associated with

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming

I am using 'Advanced Custom Fields' and i have created an archive page to display posts from a custom post type of 'property_sales'

this is the full template

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <header>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  </header>
  <div class="location">
      <?php the_field('location')?>  
  </div>
  <div class="photoframe">
       <a href="sales"><img class="responsive" src="<?php the_field('property_image')?>" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="price">£
     <?php the_field('price')?>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-summary">
     <p>Added on <?php get_template_part('templates/property-meta'); ?></p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightmovelink">
       <a href="<?php the_field('link')?>" target="_new">View Full Listing</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="clear">
</article>
```

I was wondering what code I need to put in the tag in order to link to the post each image is associated with?

Comment: Show us full code is this in loop or a single page

Comment: added the full template part - is that what you need to see? at the minute it points to the 'sales'slug but that just links it back to the page rather than the post

Comment: See my answer is that what you ask to have a post link on image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
  <div class="photoframe">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="responsive" src="<?php the_field('property_image')?>" /></a>
  </div>
```